# Error running 'Clojure REPL': Error creating RunProfileState

Tags: java, clojure

I am getting following error while doing some clojure experiments . i am new to  clojure.. while starting REPL

```
Error running 'Clojure REPL': Error creating RunProfileState:61605
```

Comment: could you please add your project.clj and global `~/.lein/profiles.clj` ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using IntelliJ? Where is its output?
It could be a lot of issues like an error in your profiles.clj or badly installation.

In my case is something like yours but the error was `Error running 'nREPL': '12' is badly configured` and I figured out that in a few weeks ago I need to change my java version, so I removed the oracle java to the open jdk and I did nothing in my IDE, what I did that fix it is

In IntelliJ IDE I go to project structure  (command + ;) and just change the **Project SDK** to a new one

I'm not saying that it will fix your problem but I think it good at least put it here to help other